# Going into sculpt mode is creating a huge amount of extra verts

Tags: sculpting

I have been sculpting a character and currently I only have the head done but for some reason in sculpt mode it's 33 million verts but when I go into object mode it's only 87k verts. The issue is that 33 million verts is lagging the viewport.

Comment: It's likely you use Multires modifier subdivided around 5 times. That's too much especially only for the head, it doesn't require that much geometry. Delete some subdivisions from the Multires and continue sculpting.